# ASP.NET multiple public override string ToString()

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to apply 2 functions like so,

public override string ToString(){
       return id.ToString();
}

public override string ToString(){
       return order.ToString();
}

and I get this error,

already defines a member called tostring with the same parameter types

is there away I can return two values in 1 ToString override ?

Comment: No. How would that make any kind of sense? How would you know which method you wanted to call? (Technically you *could* do this with explicit interface implementation, but please don't...) What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: the id and order are defined as public uint I am trying to use public override string ToString() so they return as strings. the id already had this code so it returns as string, I am trying to do the same thing for the order

Comment: I hope this makes sense

Comment: Can you provide and example of what your desired output would be upon calling the `ToString` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to two uints as strings and your class is like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
     public uint id = 1;
     public uint order = 2;
}
```

You can call it as follows:

```
MyClass instance = new MyClass();
string myValue1 = instance.id.ToString();
string myValue2 = instance.order.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

No.  You could create a method that returned a collection of strings, or a custom object that has two string properties, etc.  If you wanted to do that though then you wouldn't be able to override the `object.ToString` method, as its signature requires it to return a string.

Alternatively you could concatenate the two strings that you have together and return a new (single) string with the data of both of the other strings that you have.